# Getting "undefined" when reading data from file into JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

[image: Extra space][image: undefined]I am creating a file with PHP and then reading the data written in the file using PHP.  Once is it all created in a variable, I echo it to JS.  The issue is that somehow a the next blank line of the file is being saved into the variable.  This is creating a "undefined" everywhere that I am using that data inside of JS.  Any ideas on how to get rid of the blank space/undefined in JS? The issue may be in the PHP, is there any way to tell them PHP to not read the next line if it's empty? Thanks in advance.

PHP and echoing to JS

```
<?php
        try {
          $openInputData = fopen("../Data/IncomeData.txt", r) or die("Unable to open file.");
          $rawInputData = fread($openInputData,filesize("../Data/IncomeData.txt"));
          fclose($openInputData);
          $inputData = $rawInputData;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
          $errCatch = "$e";
        }
        ?>
        <!--Echo's the PHP file data to a JS variable-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
              var inputData = <?php echo(json_encode($inputData))?>;
              document.onload(readFile(inputData));
        </script>
```

JS Function where the data is split.

```
function readFile(inputData)
{
    for(var x=0; x<inputData.length; x++){
      var data = inputData.split("\n");
      var dataSplit = data[x].split("\t");
      var dataDate = dataSplit[0];
      var dataFrequency = dataSplit[1];
      var dataAmount = dataSplit[2];
      inOutTable(dataAmount, dataDate);
    }
    incomeStatus(dataAmount);
}
```

Comment: does `var inputData = <?php echo(json_encode($inputData))?>;` look OK in the web page source (ctrl-u in the browser)?

Comment: Shouldn't document.onload(readFile(inputData)) be document.onload = readFile(inputData); ?

Comment: It may need to be.  I can try it, but onload is working as I would expect at the moment. I also added an image of what it looks like.  The php echo looks good except the undefined which is the blank line at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

if your script is echoing the correct data then try adding single quotes around your php echo statement
like this

```
var inputData = '<?php echo(json_encode($inputData))?>';
```

Comment: I added a picture that shows perfectly what I'm trying to fix, using the ' ' that you mentioned.  You can see that an extra line is read.  The closing " should be at the end of the 10th line, not the next.  How would I bring it back or tell it not to read to the next blank line?